# Mongodb and Express.js: Automatically creating the db and collections based on Models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, orm, nosql

In Hibernate we can automatically create db and tables (SQL databases) using entity classes. Is it possible to achieve the same facility in Express.js using Mongodb(NoSql).

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve, an example of your ideal solution would be good so we could suggest similar approaches / alternatives.

Comment: if there is no collection of a given name is exist, the collection will be created using the model Schema of that collection.

Comment: Hey Fathma, I believe Mongo DB automatically supports this by default.

E.g. if you go to mongo and you go db.testCollectionName.create({ a: 1 }) then it will create a new collection called 'testCollectionName' in the already existing db 'db' and add a new record on there with the following values { _id: ..., a: 1 }.

So in saying that, I can think of two options for your use case:
1) Use the NodeJS mongodb driver (google "mongo nodejs" = https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)
2) Use Mongoose (google "mongo orm odm js" = https://mongoosejs.com/)

I recommend Option 2 for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run a local mongodb server and start the application.
When mongoose tries to connect to databse mentioned in the app it creates the database if there is none. Also when you save a document the collections is created automatically

This will create the database on the first run

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_HOST+"/"+process.env.DB_NAME, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

This will create the collection for you :

```
const model = mongoose.model('Model',new mongoose.Schema({
                             // your schema here
                            });
 var document = new Model({
                     //your document here
                });
document.save((e)=>{
         if(e) console.log(e);
        // document created in the models collection in database
       });
```